# Read only Drives 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: mount, drive, read-only

I can't create folders on my HDD or my system drive, when I try to change the location of a folder to one of this drives, it says that they are in read only mode. How do I fix this?

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu? Has it always been like this or is this something that just happened? Show the error that says it is RO. This question needs some details. As written there is nothing here that can be used to help you.

Answer (score -1):

Can you show the destination directory(folder)'s permission?

Run `ls -l <one upper directory from destination directory>` in the terminal to see the permission of the directory. (ex. if directory is `/mnt/drive/folder`, `ls -l /mnt/drive`)

You should see something like this:

```
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 18 <user> <group> 4096 Apr  2 22:09 <directory name>
```

report the first section (drwxrwxr-x for example above)

By the way, is it root(/) drive/partition you mentioned as your system drive?

If so, please check your `/etc/fstab` file.

Comment: Hi, this is what i get: `df -Th`: https://imgur.com/RGNjipd.


I already managed to have access to my HDD(/dev/sda1), but i don't have access to my system SDD (/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root).

This is what i get when i run `ls -l /dev/mapper`: https://imgur.com/lkrZ1Il.


Plus, i can't access /etc/fstab: `bash: cd: /fstab: No such file or directory`.

Comment: This is a comment not a soultion.